# DD Fedora 20 VM from remote host

Tags: filesystems, dd

Salute.

I have a machine with a root privileges and ssh access only. I need to dd it for further testing before making changes or install any additional software.

But I can't understand what drive/partition I must dd.
Fdisk -l shows a great list of loop devices.
dd of /dev/sda copies only data.
This machine has bootloader different from usual like GRUB or LILO or etc.
cat /etc/redhat-release shows that it's Fedora 20.

Is it possible to copy rootfs and boot it as a new VM with GRUB?
I think it's possible because I saw a similar machine as VM.

```
[root@srv1 ~]# cat /etc/fstab 
tmpfs           /               tmpfs   noatime     0 0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   defaults,size=50M        0 0
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,noexec,nodev,size=200M 0 0
tmpfs           /var/log        tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,noexec,nodev,size=200M,mode=755 0 0
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0 0
sysfs           /sys            sysfs   defaults        0 0


[root@srv1 ~]# mount | grep -v '/mnt/'
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,noatime)
none on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=4133588k,nr_inodes=200476,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=51200k)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,size=204800k)
tmpfs on /var/log type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,size=204800k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /var/spool type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=870400k)
tmpfs on /tmp/plugin_logs type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=204800k)
tmpfs on /var/spool/plugins type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=204800k)
rootfs on /var/run/netns type rootfs (rw,noatime)
nsfs on /var/run/netns/routerbox type nsfs (rw)
/dev/sda4 on /var/empty/chroot/data type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,discard,quota,usrquota,grpquota,data=ordered)
devtmpfs on /var/empty/chroot/dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=4133588k,nr_inodes=200476,mode=755)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I understand the machine you want to clone is a VM, correct? What type of VM is it? VirtualBox. qemu, ....

Comment: Yes, it;'s VM. But I can't use any virtualization tools to copy it because I have ssh access only.

Comment: You can copy the VM disk image via `scp` if you have ssh access. You don't need no special tools for that.

Comment: How can I get the VM disk image without access to a hypervisor's level?

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what virtualization platform you're using, as seen in my above question/comment.

Comment: My problem is to copy this VM using SSH only. As if it's a remote hardware server.

Comment: I will try something like this https://askubuntu.com/questions/7809/how-to-back-up-my-entire-system , but after it, I need to make from this backup test system = bootable OS.